# NHibernate is returning 4 instances of the same row, rather than unique rows

Tags: c#, nhibernate

### **Background**

I'm a bit confused by the result I'm getting from this NHibernate query:

```
var result = (List<RatingsLipper>)_session.CreateCriteria<RatingsLipper>()
                      .Add<RatingsLipper>(xx => xx.ShareClassId == shareClassId)
                      .List<RatingsLipper>();
```

where `RatingsLipper` has the following mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="FTMS.Domain"
                   namespace="FTMS.Domain.Entities">

    <class mutable="false" name="RatingsLipper" table="LipperRating" schema="offline">

        <id name="Id" column="LipperRating_LipperId">
            <generator class="native"></generator>
        </id>

        <property name="ShareClassId" column="LipperRating_ShareClassId" />

        <property name="RatingDate" column="LipperRating_RatingDate" />
        <property name="TimePeriod" column="LipperRating_RatingTimePeriodYears" />
        <property name="TotalReturn" column="LipperRating_TotalReturn" />
        <property name="ConsistentReturn" column="LipperRating_ConsistentReturn" />
        <property name="Preservation" column="LipperRating_Preservation" />
        <property name="Expense" column="LipperRating_Expense" />

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The query produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT this_.LipperRating_LipperId             ,
       this_.LipperRating_ShareClassId         ,
       this_.LipperRating_RatingDate           ,
       this_.LipperRating_RatingTimePeriodYears,
       this_.LipperRating_TotalReturn          ,
       this_.LipperRating_ConsistentReturn     ,
       this_.LipperRating_Preservation         ,
       this_.LipperRating_Expense              
FROM   offline.LipperRating this_
WHERE  this_.LipperRating_ShareClassId = 19278 /* @p0 */
```

which in turn produces this table:

```
LipperRating_LipperId LipperRating_ShareClassId LipperRating_RatingDate LipperRating_RatingTimePeriodYears LipperRating_TotalReturn LipperRating_ConsistentReturn LipperRating_Preservation LipperRating_Expense
--------------------- ------------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------- ------------------------ ----------------------------- ------------------------- --------------------
60011179              19278                     2011-02-28 00:00:00.000 3                                  3                        2                             4                         0
60011179              19278                     2011-02-28 00:00:00.000 5                                  3                        3                             5                         0
60011179              19278                     2011-02-28 00:00:00.000 10                                 5                        4                             5                         0
60011179              19278                     2011-02-28 00:00:00.000 99                                 4                        4                             4                         0
```

### **The Problem**

the problem I'm having is that the result I'm getting from the NHibernate query consists of 4 instances of the first row, and not the 4 different results we see in the tabular output from the SQL query.

Does this have something to do with the fact that the table `LipperRating` has a composite primary key? For reference, this table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [offline].[LipperRating](
    [LipperRating_ShareClassId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LipperRating_LipperId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LipperRating_RatingDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LipperRating_RatingTimePeriodYears] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LipperRating_TotalReturn] [int] NULL,
    [LipperRating_ConsistentReturn] [int] NULL,
    [LipperRating_Preservation] [int] NULL,
    [LipperRating_Expense] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [LipperRatings_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LipperRating_ShareClassId] ASC,
    [LipperRating_LipperId] ASC,
    [LipperRating_RatingDate] ASC,
    [LipperRating_RatingTimePeriodYears] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

### **The Question**

What do I need to do to get the correct results into my `List<RatingsLipper>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out, with the help of: http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/antrad/archive/2008/02/10/how-to-map-composite-key-in-nhibernate.aspx

I needed `<composite-id>`

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="FTMS.Domain"
                   namespace="FTMS.Domain.Entities">

    <class mutable="false" name="RatingsLipper" table="LipperRating" schema="offline">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="Id" column="LipperRating_LipperId" />
            <key-property name="ShareClassId" column="LipperRating_ShareClassId" />
            <key-property name="RatingDate" column="LipperRating_RatingDate" />
            <key-property name="TimePeriod" column="LipperRating_RatingTimePeriodYears" />
        </composite-id>

        <property name="TotalReturn" column="LipperRating_TotalReturn" />
        <property name="ConsistentReturn" column="LipperRating_ConsistentReturn" />
        <property name="Preservation" column="LipperRating_Preservation" />
        <property name="Expense" column="LipperRating_Expense" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and I also had to add this to my `RatingsLipper` type:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    bool equals = false;

    if (null != obj)
    {
        RatingsLipper temp = obj as RatingsLipper;
        if (null != temp)
        {
            equals = (this.ShareClassId == temp.ShareClassId 
                && this.TimePeriod.Equals(temp.TimePeriod) 
                && this.Id.Equals(temp.Id)
                && this.RatingDate.Equals(temp.RatingDate));
        }
    }

    return equals;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 1122; // no idea of the significance of this number!

    hash += (this.ShareClassId.GetHashCode());
    hash += (this.TimePeriod.GetHashCode());
    hash += (this.Id.GetHashCode());
    hash += (this.RatingDate.GetHashCode());

    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Yep, the way NHibernate processes queries is that it first checks to see if they are in the 1st level cache. If they are then it gets it from there. Since you only had the LipperRating_LipperId as the Id previously, it loaded the first row added it to the 1st level cache. Then for each subsequent row, got it from the cache, since they all had the same id.